# How to set children heights in GridView to the maximum height among children?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to set the heights of the children of a `GridView` to the maximum height among all the children. I don't want to type a fixed value in `childrenAspectRatio` or in `mainAxisExtent`, I need the heights to adapt to the biggest child.

Code:

```dart
GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    mainAxisExtent: 256, // don't want to set this because could cause overflow or waste of blank space
                  ),
                  itemCount: prizes.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
 
                       return Card(
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Column(
 
                            children: [
                              Stack(
 
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset(prizes[index]["image"]),
                                  ]
 
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  prizes[index]["name"],
                                  style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, ),
 
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children:  [
                                    Text(
                                      prizes[index]["cost"].toString(),
                                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
 
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left : 4.0),
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                          width: 14,
                                          height: 14,
                                          child: svg),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
 
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                          RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                          )
                                      )
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    
                                  },
                                  child:  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.riscuoti,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
 
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
 
                  },
 
                ),
```

Comment: I see your options as following: 1) give up on gridview and use a listview with rows wrapped in IntrinsicHeight as children. 2) use a plugin like flutter_staggered_grid_view. 3) the fanciest and hardes option: write your own CustomMultiChildLayout

Comment: I don't know if this is what you want, but perhaps you could use a LayoutBuilder, and using its constraints you can set a fixed height for each child dividing the maxHeight by your items count (consider that you're showing two items per "line").